# How search all pdfs in a folder and get a list of files containing the search entry

Tags: pdf

Using Adobe Reader, I can do an advanced search and find all the pdfs containing the search entry. However I can't seem to export text of the search results. I can highlight the names of the files containing the search, but I can't copy the text.

I want to be able to do the search and somehow copy the results or send to to text:

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
```

I've taken to actually taking screenshots of the results and converting it to text using [an image to text converter](http://www.to-text.net/) but there must be a better way of doing this. Any suggestions?

[image]